# Multi array/object with multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to create an array or object consisting of a list like this: 29.924% 18.095%,32.933% 15.503%,24.791% 7.725%
(numbers, characters and commas)

Comment: can provide more details ? like what will be the design ?

Comment: Hint: Range, map, random * 100...

Comment: [[0.29924, 0.18095], [0.32933, 0.15503], [0.24791, 0.07725]]

Comment: your question is not clear enough: did you mean like this:
var weirdo = ["29.924% 18.095%", "32.933% 15.503%", "24.791% 7.725%"];

Answer (score 0):

YES

```
var UltimateMixedArray = ["15.33%", 15.4, ",", "AayQ!", {name: 'Key', a: [0,1]}, 0, [333, 333, 111, 222, []]];
```

Comment: Thanks!

So to confirm, what I want to do is something like this:
var myData = ["29.924% 18.095%,32.933% 15.503%,24.791% 7.725%","33.287% 15.503%,38.951% 19.392%,39.836% 12.725%","29.924% 17.910%,33.287% 15.317%,39.128% 19.206%"];

These are x and y values with % and there could be 3-5 points which are separated by commas. 
I need to get each value like myData[i];
But need it without the quotation marks.
I can't use substring because the numbers vary from 3-5.